# Read paragraph from txt. file, split into sentences, and print onto new txt. file in c#

Tags: c#, split, readfile

I am trying to write c# code, in which I am supposed to read a paragraph in a txt. file, and then split all the sentences. Then, I am supposed to print all the sentences into a new txt. file, and they still have to have all their periods, and have to be perfectly aligned. For example, if the paragraph is: **This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. And this is the third sentence.**, then the output (in a new txt. file) should be:

This is the first sentence.

This is the second sentence.

And this is the third sentence.

I wrote some code, and it all seems to be working, except that there is an empty line at the end that I don't think should be there, since I checked for empty lines. Here is my code:

```
  using System;
  using static System.Console;
  using System.IO;

 class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Open the text file using a stream reader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("a.txt"))
        {

            // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();

        string[] sentences = line.Split('.');

        using (StreamWriter newFile = new StreamWriter("b.txt"))

            for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sentences[i].Length != 0)
                {
                    string outString = sentences[i].Trim() + ".";
                    newFile.WriteLine(outString);
                    WriteLine(outString);


                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The output that I get here is:

This is the first sentence.

This is the second sentence.

And this is the third sentence.

[empty line]

I don't know why there is a space at the end of my txt. file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks so much.

Comment: Because the first character after a period is a space. <- see :) Just trim the string.

Comment: Is this a real problem or some kind of homework? I ask because sentence parsing is incredibly difficult and best left to something like Stanford NLP or Azure Text Analytics.

Comment: You should sanitize the paragraph before the split: remove leading and ending whitespace, whitespace arround periods. You can use regex.replace and patterns like: ^\s+ for leading spaces, replace with “”. \s+\.\s+ for whitespace around petiods replace with “.”, \s+$ for trailing whitespace replace with “”. After that, make sure to look at StringSplitOptions to ignore empty sentences, and you should be set!

Comment: Writing from mobile, sorry I cannot be of more help. In my previous comment replace my mention of “spaces”with “whitespace”. \s matches most whitespace characters. Perhaps some control characters can still get through, you need to test.

Comment: http://rextester.com/RTGLBE60885 Something wrong from mobile I suspect a wrong quotes character, but you’ll get the point!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try debugging this to see what the `string[] sentences` contained? Each sentence has a period and then you are splitting on it so that will give you an array of 4 lines:

1 This is the first sentence
2  This is the second sentence 
3  And this is the third sentence
4

Then you are adding a period to the end of each one, which is why your getting that extra period.

You can try adding a string.IsNullOrEmpty check on each sentence as well as a .Trim() to clean up the white space.

```
foreach (string sentence in sentences)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
       Console.WriteLine(sentence.Trim() + ".");
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx This eliminates the need for a null check

Comment: Ah this worked, thank you soooo much!! The only issue I have now is that it adds an extra empty line at the end of the text file and I can't seem to get rid of it :(

Comment: Not sure I understand your new issue, can you add more explanation?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion--in the new txt. file that my code writes, it writes the following:

This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence.
And this is the third sentence.
[blank line]

I'm just trying to get rid of the blank line that is inserted at the end, and I cannot seem to do it.

Comment: Please post your updated code by editing your question. It shouldn't be writing an empty line if you're doing a null or empty check

Comment: I tried something new, but it is still giving me one extra line with nothing on it in the new txt file (b.txt). I'll update the question with the new code!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to know:

1. Why are there spaces between sentences
2. Why are there two dots at the end

When you use the method `Split(string str)` spaces are included in the splitting. If you look at your example, there are actually some spaces between sentences, so it won't delete them.

Regarding problem #2 you're adding a dot at every sentence because the method Split eliminated them. There must be a space at the end of your example file like this: `And this is the third sentence.[space here]`. Split will put in the array the third sentence AND the space after the dot. Of course `newFile.WriteLine(sentence + ".");` add a dot at the end of every sentence, so it takes the hidden space and put a dot at the end of it. You can use the method `yourString.Trim()` to remove every space BEFORE and AFTER your string.